# .stream().filter() inside a tag

Tags: spring-boot, set, iteration, thymeleaf, spring-el

I'm working with thymeleaf on a small project. And have a setup like so.

```
public class Datacenter {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="datacenter"
private Set<Cage> cageSet = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Cage {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "datacenter_id")
private Datacenter datacenter;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="rack"
private Set<Rack> rackSet= new HashSet<>();
    
}

public class Rack {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cage_id")
private Cage cage;

private String var1;
private String var2;
private Boolean active;
}
```

Thing is that I want to have a page that has a collapsible list of datacenters and when it expands in the next row to a table that lists all the Cages defined there. Next below that I would like to have a row that shows values from one certain object Rack from the related `Set<Rack>` - more precisely only one would have the active value as `true`.

Is there an option through Thymeleaf to reference that one object using something like:

```
th:text="${cage.rackSet.stream().filter(some_filtering_here).getVar2()}"
```

Or should I create a sepparate object hierarchy on the controller level that would mimic exactly how I want the page to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these kinds of things, look at [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) and [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection).  In your case an expression like this should work:

```
th:text="${cage.rackSet.^[active].var2}"
```